# Airplay mirror iPad to mac but let audio play from iPad

Tags: ios, mac, audio, airplay

**Scenario:**
I'm trying to mirror my iPad to my iMac using the [Reflection app](http://www.reflectionapp.com/).  Everything works fine but the reason I'm doing this is to record myself making a real time mix using the app *Djay*.

**Problem:**
The audio that is streamed to my computer is off by a second, so that makes it nearly impossible to actually time my transitions right.  I want to let my iPad mirror itself but allow myself to hear the audio straight from the iPad instead to bypass that problem.  Should I use a HDMI capture card instead?  Or is there some kind of audio splitter cable that actually retrieves the audio despite airplay running?

**Side Notes:**
I do have *Djay* for Mac, the only reason I'm doing this is to have my video stand out from the regular mix videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an HDMI solution would work better in this case because you need as little latency as possible for music. The company I work for is considering trying a [Blackmagic Intensity Shuttle or Intensity Extreme HDMI interface and converter](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/), which cost US $300 at retail. I have no experience with them. You will need a Thunderbolt, PCI or USB 3 interface to your Mac to use a Blackmagic Intensity.

[image]

### Part Two

I'm also a registered user of the Reflection app, and I've been in touch with their tech support staff. They point out that latency and frame rate depend on the specifications of the WiFi router through which the iPad sends its audio and video to the Mac. When you connect the iPad's video and audio to the Mac using AirPlay, are you using a WiFi G router (slow), or a WiFi N router (five times as fast as WiFi G)? Furthermore, you should probably connect the Mac directly to the router via an Ethernet cable, and not use WiFi on the Mac at all. Test this with a WiFi N (802.11n) router in close proximity to the iPad broadcasting with AirPlay and see if performance improves and latency decreases.

If you are using this setup in performance as a DJ, you might want to set up your own router in your DJ rig, whether it's connected to the Internet or not, so you can ensure the fastest connection between the iPad and the Mac.

If that doesn't produce acceptable results, then the HDMI hardware might be the next thing to try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll perform the steps you suggested with my Wifi N router and directly connect it to my Mac.  My only other concern is that the Reflection app in the past glitch causing a very high ear splitting pitch during my practice session.  This still occurs even after the latest update.  You mentioned that they are very responsive on their tech support so I'll bring that to their attention.

If there still is a lag performing your steps I'm afraid my cash balance is too low to purchase the $300 HDMI converter.

Comment: I have not listened critically to the audio coming over AirPlay with Reflection, because I'm not using it for music purposes myself. 

I will also add that while I have not tested it, I suspect that the HDMI solution would give you the highest audio quality, which is important to you.